# Integrity check against package repository?

Tags: apt, security

When there are security updates, I review and install them as soon as possible and think about using automatic updates.

From time to time I want to boot from a clean boot CD and check if the system has been compromised.

For that reason, I want to check if any packages / binaries have been modified, check the bootloader, check for rootkits.

Let's suppose I booted from a clean boot CD and mounted the hdd filesystem.

How can I get list of all sha256 hash sums of all installed binaries and configuration files and check them against the versions from Debian repository?

I have looked into intrusion detection systems (debsums,) Afick, AIDE, FCheck, Integrit, Osiris, OSSEC, Samhain, Tripwire, but they all have in common, that they want to create a known-good database before auditing. This doesn't scale very well, because updates are pretty frequent, which render that known-good database less useful. Re-creating the known-good database after updating isn't very safe either - let's say apt-get had a bug and installed a malicious package, then the checksum of that malicious package would end up in the known-good database.

I think the real solution is checking against the distribution's package repository. How can I do that?

I've checked http://wiki.debian.org/SecureApt#How_to_manually_check_for_package.27s_integrity already, but instructions are incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

For checking the integrity of an individual file in a package against the repositories, there's no easy way short of downloading the package. The repositories typically provide these files:

- `Release{,.gpg}`, `InRelease` - these provide the hashes of the `Packages` files.
- The `Packages` file provides hashes of the packages.
- The `Contents` file, where present, provides filelists of packages.

There's no file which provides the hashes of individual files - these are contained in the packages (`DEBIAN/md5sums` in the `control` archive).

So, if you don't trust the local system:

1. You'll have to download the `Contents` file (if available).
2. Match the file to the package using that file and download the package.
3. Then use the `md5sums` to verify the file.

If a `Contents` file is not available, and you don't trust the local system, have fun downloading *every* package to see what provided the file.

This does not scale.